# How efficiently can the bitwise and operation of two numbers be done?

Tags: arithmetic, computational-complexity

Consider two integers `a` and `b`. The objective is to find all the integers `c < a` such that `c & b = c`. Apart from the naive `O(a)` solution, where we check all the integers, is there an efficient way of doing this.

Ex:

```
a = 9 , b = 12
c = {0,4,8} [ 0 & 12 = 0, 4 & 12 = 4, 8 & 12 = 8 ]
```

PS: `a` is expected to be smaller in degree than `b`, if it can help in some way.

Comment: @user8734617 yeah, i will update it :)

Comment: In the worst case you will still need to output all numbers $\lt a$, that is, if $b$ is all-ones, so you cannot escape the worst case to be $O(a)$. (BTW isn't it $O(a\log a)$ because you need to output every digit of every number?)

Comment: Probably a short example would help to illustrate your problem.  In particular I'm not sure what $a$ is smaller "in drgree" than $b$ is intended to mean.

Comment: @hardmath i meant `log(a) < log(b)` to the base 10.

Comment: @hardmath added a simple example.

Comment: If $a$ and $b$ are both positive, then $\log a < \log b$ if and only if $a < b,$ so you might as well not bother taking logarithms for that purpose. It might (or might not) be helpful to have more background information on _why_ you need this calculation, since the desired application may have some useful properties that you didn't realize would help.

Comment: @DavidK what I meant to convey is that if `a` is of the order `10^3` ... `b` will be of the order of around `10^7`.

Comment: Since that's what you want, that's what you should have written. What other information did you forget to tell us?

Answer (score 1):

For each bit, if that bit in $b$ is $0$ you must have that bit in $c$ be zero.  If that bit in $b$ is $1$, that bit in $c$ can be either $0$ or $1$.  If $b \gt a$ you can ignore any bits that are too bit to fit in $a$.  You can find the bits of interest in something like $\log a$ time as there are $\log_2 a$ of them.  Assuming half the bits of interest are $1$s the final list will be about $\sqrt{\min (a,b)}$ in size, while if $b$ has all $1$s in the length of $a$ your list will be all the numbers less than $a$.  This gives a worst case time of $O(a)$ and an expected time of $O(\sqrt a)$

Comment: Thanks Ross. I was trying on similar lines, but I was wondering if some property or pattern can be generalized for the set of numbers `c & b = c` given `b`. It would be helpful if you could suggest any similar approaches.

Comment: I described the pattern.  Take the binary of $b$ and replace each $1$ with a star, meaning you can have either a $0$ or a $1$ in that bit.  When you said  "find all integers" it sounded to me like you wanted a list.  The thing that takes all the time is making that list.  If $a$ has a million bits, there will be something like $2^{500,000}$ numbers in the list.  Coming up with the description is fast, but turning that into a list will take forever.